# Numba can't use math.isqrt

Tags: python, numba

I'm using numba for the first time and I do this checkPrime function and I want to use math.isqrt function but numba returns this error:

```
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'isqrt' of type Module(<module 'math' (built-in)>)
```

What can I do for solving this problem? Thanks

Code:

```
import math

@jit(nopython=True)
def checkPrime(prime: int) -> bool:
    isPrime: bool = True
    for num in range(3, int(math.isqrt(prime)), 2):
        if prime % num == 0:
            isPrime = False
            break
    return isPrime

@jit(nopython=True)
def main():
    print(2)
    for num in range(3, 100, 2):
        if checkPrime(num):
            print(num)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Unlike the majority of Python `math` module functions, `isqrt` isn't a simple wrapper around a libm math function, so it's not surprising that Numba doesn't support it. (I'd guess that the same is true for a number of other `math` module functions, like `math.factorial`, `math.comb` and `math.perm`.) If anything, this seems like a feature request for the Numba developers.

Comment: You should be able to use `int(math.sqrt(...))`.  Or, if it's really that important, just write a function to do 2 or 3 cycles of Newton-Raphson.  That's a quick way to do square root.